# Summarizing numbers over Distinct values in DAX Power BI

Tags: powerbi, sum, dax, distinct-values

I am having trouble receiving correct result when trying to sum numbers over Distinct values (in DAX Power BI)

I have the following table - Tbl_Eposode:

[image]

I expect to have total numbers of [Episode] = 12

But I keep having SUM of [Episode] = 36.

My code just summarizes all Episode values instead only summarizing unique Episodes
(by EpisodeID, ProgramID))

This is my code:

```
     # Pre Homeless Days = CALCULATE(SUM('Tbl_Episode'[Episode]),                    
                                     ALLEXCEPT('Tbl_Episode','Tbl_Episode'[EpisodeID],
                                                             'Tbl_Episode'[ProgramID],
                                                             'Tbl_Episode'[ClientID]))
```

Please Help!

Comment: Looks like a modeling problem.  Why isn't "Episode" on a table that has one row per EpisodeID?  You can jump through hoops in DAX to work around this, but it's always better to have a model that makes that unnecessary.

Comment: `SUMX(CALCULATETABLE(VALUES(tbl[EpisodeID]),ALL()),CALCULATE(SELECTEDVALUE(tbl[EPISODE])))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As David Brownse says, this really needs remodelling. However, if you are adamant that this is the way to go then:

```
# Pre Homeless Days = 
  SUMX( SUMMARIZE(Tbl_Episode, Tbl_Episode[EpisodeID], Tbl_Episode[ProgramID], Tbl_Episode[ClientID],Tbl_Episode[Episode]), Tbl_Episode[Episode])
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just group the table in Power Query by EpisodeID, ClientID and ProgramID and compute the maximum of Episode and compute the sumation.

```
= Table.Group(#"Reordered Columns", {"EpisodeID", "ClientID", "ProgramID"}, {{"Max_Episode", each List.Max([Episode]), type nullable number}})
```

DAX:

```
Pre Homeless Days 2 = SUM(Max_Episode[Max_Episode])
```

Output in Table:

[image]

New Table "Max_Episode" created in Fields Pane:

[image]